# Strange behavior when updating a sub array with lag function using ShiftedArrays

Tags: julia

When I try to update a sub array of a vector with the lagged one, the result is a bit strange, is it the expected behavior?

MWE:

```
using ShiftedArrays
x = [1,2,3,4,missing];
y = lag(view(x, 2:3));
x[2:3] = y;
 x
5-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 1
  missing
  missing
 4
  missing
```

x[2:3] are both missing.

Answer (score 1):

this is because `y` is `lag` of a view, so when you update the `x[2:3]`, first it sets `x[2]` to `missing`, because that's the first element of `y`, but that makes the second element of `y` missing as well. (originally, the second element of `y` is `2`). So by the time it sets `x[3]`, it's `missing` too.

you need to make a copy somewhere, or update the array in reverse order.

btw, your code isn't doing much, if you simply want to lag by 1 and insert a missing somewhere, you can simply insert it:

```
julia> x[2:3] .= missing, x[2]

julia> x
5-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 1
  missing
 2
 4
  missing
```

Comment: This answer is not helpful, e.g. if `y = view(x2, 2:3)` and `y[1] = missing`, then `x[2:3] = y` is `[missing, missing, 3, 3, missing, 4]`

Comment: some typos in the last comment, and I cannot edit it, but, I guess, you get my point.

Comment: I can't help you without knowing what you want, you can use `y` without `view` to get the correct result. @هنروقتان

Comment: For some views, Julia will make preventative copies to avoid such aliasing issues. If you want a project, you could try to make ShiftedArrays hook into the same machinery, `Base.unalias` and friends. But if you just want results, then be aware that broadcasting from one view of memory to another view of the same opens the door to all kinds of race conditions.

Comment: @mcabbott this is not broadcasting it is a simple `setindex`.

Comment: @jling note that this is just MWE, your workaround is not helpful.

Comment: what if you just remove `view()` and let `y = lag(x[2:3])`? does that not work?